# How to deploy bpel project on ODE server

Tags: tomcat, bpel, ode

My `BPEL` project working fine in my local . But i need to deploying that project on my server how can i export `BPEL` project war file or something else ??

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am stucked same way. BPEL Working fine on Local, but when I copy same BPEL folder to Other tomcat in ode/WEB_INF/processes nothing happens. I do see a .deployed file generated, but webservice actually not accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found it. 
Hope it helps.

1. Zip the files in below structure.

   So suppose you have BPELDemo.bpel BPELDemowsdl.wsdl deploy.xml

   The BPELDemo.zip should Directly content these files.

   NO other Fodler Structure.

   2. then go to [localhost:8080/ode/index.hmtl](http://localhost:8080/ode/index.html). go to deployment tab.

   Select the ZIP file, and Give name as BPELDemo and Click OK.

This will dpeloy the the BPEL correctly.